# radio button matrix group javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, matrix, radio-button

I am completely lost as to how I can solve this. 
I need to create a matrix of radio buttons, column 1 to 3 and rows A to C.
       A B C
    1 (o) (o) (o)
    2 (o) (o) (o)
    3 (o) (o) (o)

```
<table>   
<tr> 
<td>1</td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_1" value="Radio A" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_2" value="Radio B" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_3" value="Ipod A" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>2</td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_1" value="Radio A" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_2" value="Radio B" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_3" value="Ipod A" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>3</td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_1" value="Radio A" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_2" value="Radio B" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_3" value="Ipod A" onclick="checkMatrixRow(this)"></td> 
</tr>
</table>

<script>
// radio buttons
var columns = new    Array('ljudkalla_1','ljudkalla_2','ljudkalla_3');

function getSelectedIndex(array) {
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].checked) return i;
}
}

function checkMatrixRow(input) {

var n = getSelectedIndex(input.form[input.name]); // index of selected button in a radio group (= row number)   


for (var i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
    if (columns[i] != input.name) {
        input.form[columns[i]][n].checked = false;
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I should only be able to choose one button per row and column, so if I have chosen A1 and then click on B1, the first one should uncheck.  The big issue is really the C column. In this column I should be able to choose all three, C1 C2 and C3, but same thing here if I have chosen C2 and then check A2 the first one should uncheck.
I have been scanning the internet for days and I cannot find anything, so if anyone knows of a tutorial or just some information on how to solve this I would be deeply grateful.

Or perhaps it is not possible to do it this way?

Thanks

Linda

Comment: it is a logical question linda you need to post your js code, so that people can look at what you tried and edit it as per your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I some how stumbled upon the answer while playing with it O_o

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jn3g/)

Basically you use the class name in conjunction with the name attribute to get a multi-axis radio button.  Then the radio buttons are reset based on the same name and you reset the others based on class name.  Elegant yet simple.

#### Markup

---

```
<table>   
<tr> 
<td>1</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_1" value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_1" value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_1" value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>2</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_2" value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_2" value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_2" value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>3</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_3" value="Radio A"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_3" value="Radio B"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_3" value="Ipod A"></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

#### jQuery

---

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("input."+this.className).not($(this)).each(function(){
        this.checked = false;
    });
});
```

### Edit

---

#### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jn3g/1/)

I added another cool little feature to this with the following code

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("input."+this.className).not($(this)).each(function(){
        this.checked = false;
    });
    $("input:not([name='"+this.name+"'])").each(function(){
        if ($("input[name='"+this.name+"']:checked").length < 1)
            if($("input."+this.className+":checked").length < 1)
                this.checked = true;
    });
});
```

This enables it to automatically change a radio button selection if another selection deselects it... maybe you should just see the demo. :P It's a little hard to explain I guess.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, however I cannot get this to work on my webpage and I don't understand why

Comment: this is awesome. I really like demo 2.

Answer (score 0):

You may use my plugin https://github.com/zevero/jquery-checkbox-table

```
$('#container').checkbox_table({
   cols: ['A','B','C'],
   rows: [1,2,3]
 });
```