# script works on jsfiddle but not in my webpage jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jsfiddle

With help from @Joseph I have managed to create this script that works exactly the way I want it to  on jsfiddle. However, when I use the exact same script on my webpage it does not do anything, it ignores the script inside the if and else and works like a normal radio button would do. I don't get any errror messages and I am using:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js
```

The only thing that I can think of is that it does not work using "this"? How would I solve that?

My script can be found at:
http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/15013/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var $knapp = $(this).val();      

    if(($knapp=='1c') || ($knapp=='2c')|| ($knapp=='3c')) {
        this.checked = true;  
    }else{
        $("input[type='radio']."+this.className).not($(this)).each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
});

<table>   
<tr> 
<td>1</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_1" value="1a"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_1" value="1b"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_1" value="1c"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>2</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_2" value="2a"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_2" value="2b"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_2" value="2c"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>3</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_3" value="3a"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_3" value="3b"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_3" value="3c"></td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And [this](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/jsfiddle.net) is why you should include code **in** the question, rather than linking to it externally.

Comment: sorry, question has been updated

Comment: use firebug/chrome dev toolbar - and show the error/output

Comment: Your code is nothing like the code @Joseph created in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041003/radio-button-matrix-group-javascript-jquery unless I am missing something

Comment: @andyb no, I have changed it so that it works the way I need it to do. In his code I was not able to choose all three at the same time 1c, 2c and 3c, so I tried to change it

Comment: Could you please post the complete page you are having a problem with. We need to see the actual code that is causing the problem. Also could you please remove the screenshot as it does not help describe the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/y9BJR/) is what you are after, correct? Does this work on your local machine?

```
$("input").click(function() {
    if (this.className.indexOf('3') === -1) {
        $("input." + this.className).not($(this)).each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: nice, but no it does not work local, but it works fine in jsfiddle. I am now trying to debug with firebug

Comment: I would like to say thanks to everybody for helping me, unfortunately I cannot get it to work on my website. I will have to try and find a different solution to this without using jquery.

Comment: It seems very strange that it works on jsFiddle but not on your machine. Are all files downloading properly (no red lines in Net tab in Firebug)? Does the Firebug console show any errors? I would advise against abandoning jQuery, there is no reason it shouldn't work for you on your local machine, and you will find it much easier to do cross browser compatible scripts using it. Are you referring to the version of jQuery hosted on the Google CDN or a local file?

Answer (score 1):

You are including jQuery twice. One is the [*minified*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) version, denoted by the `min.js`. You only need one of those libraries. I suggest using the minified version to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an error in your HTML, because it works here locally when creating the HTML from scratch.

You can also try to debug your version with Firebug or the debuggers of Safari or Chrome. Put a breakpoint in your code, and trying out the jQuery selectors manually in the console can help to spot most problems.

This one works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var $knapp = $(this).val();      

    if(($knapp=='1c') || ($knapp=='2c')|| ($knapp=='3c')) {
        this.checked = true;  
    }else{
        $("input[type='radio']."+this.className).not($(this)).each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<table>   
<tr> 
<td>1</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_1" value="1a"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_1" value="1b"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_1" value="1c"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>2</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_2" value="2a"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_2" value="2b"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_2" value="2c"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>3</td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_1" name="ljudkalla_3" value="3a"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_2" name="ljudkalla_3" value="3b"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" class="ljudkalla_3" name="ljudkalla_3" value="3c"></td> 
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 yes I found the same thing. No problems locally or in the linked jsFiddle